# python help function documentation

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-module, python-packaging

I have problems finding the documentation of the help function in Python 2.7, I have this code:

```
from google.cloud.gapic import pubsub as ps
print dir(ps)
help(ps)
```

and it returns :

```
['__doc__', '__name__', '__path__']
Help on package google.cloud.gapic.pubsub in google.cloud.gapic:

NAME
    google.cloud.gapic.pubsub

FILE
    (built-in)

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    v1 (package)
```

My question is what does PACKAGE CONTENTS: v1 (package) mean?

Becouse "`v1`" doesn't appear in dir() output and I can't access to it by typping `ps.v1`

```
help(ps.v1)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'v1'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask].  Have you tried to look at the source for `google.cloud.gapic.pubsub`?

Comment: Yes. But this question's came from a problem in the library, and a conflict with other google library.

Comment: Doesn't sound like SO is the place to resolve it.

Comment: I just want to understand why if PACKAGE CONTENTS have 'v1' i can't access to it

Comment: It says the `v1` is a package, so you should be able to access it with `import google.cloud.gapic.pubsub.v1`.